# What functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ satisfy $u(x) = v'(x)$ and $u'(x) = v(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, systems-of-equations

I recently came across a problem in a calculus textbook which involved functions satisfying the relation $u(x) = v'(x)$ and $u'(x) = v(x)$. The problem didn't list any specific functions that for which this is true, so I was quite curious to see what functions have this property. I'm aware that there are probably some very simple solutions, but can anyone think of some more interesting examples?

Comment: $e^x$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: It follows that $u''=u$. If you've studied elementary differential equations it's easy to see that this happens if and only if $u=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}$ for constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Yeah there are some very simple functions that do this, but I was looking for some more interesting ones.

Comment: @wrb98 Unclear who that comment was addressed to. I gave you all  of them...

Comment: The "interesting" functions that satisfy those conditions are hyperbolic sine and cosine - which are among the general solution David has provided.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this means
$$u''(x) = u(x) \text{ and }v''(x) = v(x)$$
Hence, we have
$$u(x) = ae^x + be^{-x} \text{ and }v(x) = ae^x - be^{-x}$$